# How are a phone and a cellular network tower connected?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I know that voice communications from one cell phone to another pass through the nearest cellular network tower first. The word we use is *"to connect"*, and a phone would ordinarily display the strength of this connexion, that seems to continuously decrease as I walk away from the reach of a tower.

It looks like this *"connexion"* is a physical link of some kind, and it gets *"thinner"* in some way as distance increases. What is the nature of this connexion? How can it be measured?

Comment: Please help me assign the correct tags.

Comment: I do not mind if it is closed as a duplicate either, if there is a canonical answer of some sort.

Comment: I assigned a tag. It is a two-word answer as well!

Comment: FWIW: Your cell phone actually is a high-tech two-way radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection between a cell tower and a mobile phone is largely a question for engineering, in terms of what constitutes the initiation, maintenance, and cessation of the connection.

However, the means by which these occur are via radio waves. Like all electromagnetic radiation, radio transmissions observe the inverse square law. This means that the power of the radio transmissions detected by a receiver of a fixed size reduces at a rate that is inversely proportional to the square of the distance to the transmitter.

Let's say that signals from a transmitter arrive at a receiver 1m with a power of 1mW. At 2 meters, it will be 250uW. At 4 meters, it will be 125uW and so on.

At some point, the power at the receiver is so low that the level of radio noise from other sources "drown out" the incoming signal such that the data stream cannot be understood at the connection cannot be maintained.

Comment: This isn't really right in few respect. First, the inverse-square drop-off assumes uniform emission from the tower antenna, which you don't necessarily get.  Second, in most environments a lot of the drop-off is due to interference of obstacles.

Comment: *is largely a question for engineering* this question currently has 3 close votes for this reason. If you think a question is "largely" of another topic/subject, you shouldn't answer it.

Comment: @KyleKanos, largely, but not exclusively. Also, there were no apparent close votes when I answered it.

Comment: @Dancrumb there were 3 when you answered it, but you can't see them because you have insufficient reputation points (requires 1k rep).

Comment: @KyleKanos I asked a question, I received an answer, everyone is happy. Why do you hate?

Comment: @Ignat I don't hate anything, but you asked a clearly off-topic question and received an answer that acknowledges the off-topicness & the person responded anyway. There is a reason we have specific subject matter in this site: to prevent anyone from asking any old question they have; by someone willfully ignoring such topicality, it violates the principles of having a narrow focused site (to just physics)

Comment: @KyleKanos However, my question is not exclusively about engineering. Moreover, I am in no way requiring an answer concerning _"application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem"_. The answer given is about physics, and I am happy with it. No violation.